# "Intellectual-property-law" tag is misspelled

Tags: bug, status-completed

I'm not sure if this is the proper place to do this, but I wanted to bring it to the attention of moderators that the "intellectual-property-law" tag is misspelled "intelletual-property-law". It makes the tag that much harder to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The misspelt [intelletual-property-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intelletual-property-law) has been fixed. Long live [intellectual-property-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intellectual-property-law)!